# Why doesn't the time on my device match up with Calender HOUR_OF_DAY, MINUTE

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

I am setting an alarm using alarm manager. The alarm is working fine but it doesn't go exactly at the time my device changes minute.

Obviously there is a discrepancy between where the display at the top of the screen is getting its time and the the Calander API.

I am getting the time and setting it for alarm manager like this:

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 03);

alarmActivityRecieverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),AlarmNotificationReciever.class );
alarmActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, alarmActivityRecieverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,alarmActivityPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Please consult the docs for [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). As of KitKat, if your `targetSdkVersion`>=19, `setRepeating()` is inexact. If you want exact times, you'll need to use a `setExact*()` method, and set the alarm again for the desired interval each time it fires.

Comment: Ok cool thanks! Just looked over the docs you linked and there doesn't seem to be setRepeatingExact? How is that handled then.

Comment: Scratch that. Just found out from google. Thanks